# ios access other apps TextBox

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2

I am working on a project where I have to access TextBox/TextField/EditText of other apps like messenger/whatsapp/Viber/etc... on (Android/IOS).

I did get it done with Android using Accessiblity service, but I am stuck for iOS.

Is there any way that I can follow or explore to create a service (Background Apps) that can access TextBoxes of other apps?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, applications are sandboxed and cannot access each other.  There are several ways for two applications to communicate with one another, but they rely on the two applications coöperating – you cannot do it by yourself and you can't access the UI of the other application.

Answer (score 0):

That interoperatibility was introduced in iOS 8, but anyway you will need to have access to the source code of those apps in order to accomplish this.

So I guess the answer for your question would be no.